# Multiple JOINS - Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:

Classes:

```
id  class   
1   X C     
2   VI B    
3   XII F   
4   X C     
5   VI B    
6   VIII A
```

Students:

```
    id  id_student  class   
    2   1 [->]      X C     
    3   4 [->]      VI B    
    5   7 [->]      X C
```

Grades

```
Id  id_student  grade   
3   1 [->]      8       
4   1 [->]      7       
5   1 [->]      10      
6   1 [->]      8       
7   1 [->]      9       
8   4 [->]      5       
9   4 [->]      7       
10  4 [->]      9   
11  1 [->]      4       
12  1 [->]      9       
13  7 [->]      10
```

Absences:

```
id  id_student
1   1 [->]              
2   1 [->]              
3   1 [->]              
4   4 [->]              
5   1 [->]              
6   1 [->]              
7   1 [->]              
8   7 [->]
```

What I want is to select all classes from Classes Table (only those who have students) and 
count the number of students for every class, the average of their grades and number of absences.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT classes.class, COUNT(distinct students.id_students) AS nr_students, AVG(grades.grade) AS avg_grades
FROM classes 
    INNER JOIN students ON students.student = clases.class
    INNER JOIN grades ON students.students = grades.id_student
GROUP BY class
```

Until now everything is great. Output (PHP):

```
Class  Nr_Students  Avg_Grades
VI B   1           7.0000    
X C    2           8.1250
```

But I want to count every row from Absences table and print the total number of absences for every class.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Class  Nr_Students  Avg_Grades  Nr_Abcences
VI B   1           7.0000       1
X C    2           8.1250       7
```

I can't change the DB!

Thank you.

Comment: your `JOIN ON` conditions look highly suspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that some of the column and table names will need to be changed, since your query doesn't match your schema at all. The following works though:

```
SELECT s.class
    ,COUNT(s.id_student) AS nr_students
    ,g.avg_grade AS avg_grades
    ,SUM(a.cnt_absences) AS absences
FROM students s 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT s.class, AVG(g.grade) AS avg_grade 
    FROM grades g
    INNER JOIN students s ON g.id_student = s.id_student
    GROUP BY s.class
  ) g ON s.class = g.class
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_student, COUNT(id) AS cnt_absences 
    FROM absences  
    GROUP BY id_student
  ) a ON s.id_student = a.id_student
GROUP BY s.class, g.avg_grade
```

See it [working on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dbf9/15/0)

Comment: Why is AVG_GRADES from X C equal with 8.92855. If I do that manually it gives me 8.125.  Another problem is when I put your querry in my script the nr of students and the nr of absences is doubled. I don't know wht, maybe you had this problem in the past. 
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: thats because you have classes with different ids and the same name. so student 1 belongs to 2 classes and student 2 belongs to 2 classes - if you changed it to group by `c.id` rather than `c.class` you'd the problem. I'll look into why the average is wrong.

Comment: If it is intentional that there are different class ids with the same class name, I can change the query to support it.

Comment: I put distinct before c.class and c.id rather than c.class as you said. The avg is still 8.92855.

Comment: Updated the answer and fiddle.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you very much OGHaza. Unbelievable. Much harder than I thought. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Only subquery is provide:

```
 SELECT classes.class, COUNT(distinct students.id_students) AS nr_students, AVG(grades.grade) AS avg_grades, COALESCE(ab.Nr_Abcences, 0)
    FROM classes 
        INNER JOIN students ON students.student = clases.class
        INNER JOIN note ON students.students = grades.id_student
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT class, COUNT(ab.id) AS NR_Abcences FROM Students INNER JOIN Absences ab ON ab.id_student = Students.id_student GROUP BY Students.class) ab ON ab.class = clases.class
    GROUP BY class
```

I didn't test this query.